# getting width of content, not viewport using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried the following and gotten the viewport width:

```
document.documentElement.clientWidth
```

and

```
window.innerWidth
```

However, what I want to get is the width of the **content** including overflow, for example if I had an image on the page `<img src=".." style="width: 4000px !important;" />`.  In other words, the entire scrollable width. How would I do this?

Comment: The `Element.scrollWidth` read-only property is a measurement of the width of an element's content, including content not visible on the screen due to overflow. If the element's content can fit without a need for horizontal scrollbar, its scrollWidth is equal to clientWidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `scrollWidth` for the body [scrollWidth docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth) . Also please don't use `!important` . Only use it as a **last** resort

```js
console.log(document.body.scrollWidth)
```

```html
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width: 4000px;" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with Element.offsetWidth

```
document.documentElement.offsetWidth
```

You can read more about offsetWidth [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth)

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I am kind of curious as well and this seemed a solution I stumbled upon as well.

Comment: @Barrosy Just check it and see if it works. https://jsfiddle.net/c1p2k3of/